# C# webbrowser sudden refresh

Tags: c#, forms, drop-down-menu, webbrowser-control, refresh

I use Visual studio 2008.
In my form there is a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control.
I have a custom header in the form just above the webBrowser control.
In the webBrowser there is a form with a select/drop-down thing made with html.
When I click the drop-list and it overlaps the custom header (because of the many options in it) The browser refreshes.
When I click it on a higher res version so the box doesn't touch the header, this refresh doesn't happen and everything works fine.

how can I solve this refresh problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to see some source code to help you further. Without it, I can only suggest you try to shorten the list or re-distribute the user interface in a different way if possible.

Also, is there some javascript referenced anywhere by any chance?

Comment: Sorry for the extreme late reply, but I tried simply removing the JavaScript to see if it was interfering with the application. And it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.